# Supress XML comment warnings in build output, but not in IDE

Tags: .net-core, roslyn

We recently enabled XML comment generation in our project, and so all uncommented classes and methods display a warning. This is useful in the IDE, but pollutes are build output with thousands of warnings about a lack of comments. Ideally, we'd like to keep the warnings in the IDE, but not have them appear in the build output.

I've tried disabling the error in the build settings, but in our IDE (Rider) this also disables the warning within the IDE itself. So is there a way to suppress this warning in the build output, without affecting the IDE's warning messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this to you projects or Directory.Build.props:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'">
  <NoWarn>CS1570;$(NoWarn)</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That will not warn on CS1570 if it's not a design-time build.